# Document Scanning using MVC3 application

Tags: c#

We need integrate document scanning functionality with our MVC3 application. Any Microsoft provided libraries for this solution?

Comment: our mean OCR of uploaded document pictures?

Comment: I did write a little library based on [WIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition). It adds some support for scanning multiple pages at once from ADF scanners. See http://adfwia.codeplex.com . No idea how you'll manage this from a web application/browser. You can't have server code just access something on the user machine.

Comment: the library in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432009/How-to-Capture-Edit-and-Upload-Images-Through-Your) is not provided by Microsoft per se, but i think it fits your need well

Answer (score 0):

Personally i used the twain API, i know its interop but its not really difficult.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner

or something more modern like:

http://www.gdpicture.com/products/dotnet/document-imaging-sdk.php